# Set Font Size and HighLight Text in PDF Library MUPDF in Android

Tags: android, text, highlighting, font-size, pdf-reader

I am loading PDF file via MUPDF and i added feature like brightness. I found bit difficult to increase the font size and highlight some text in the loaded pdf can anybody suggest on which file i we have set size and text color. Any help is appreciated i am following https://github.com/bhavyahmehta/Pdf-Reader---Writer/blob/master/Pdf_%20Reader_Writer/README.md. Below is the code where i am setting font size.

```
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                System.out.println("canvas");
                float scale = mSourceScale*(float)getWidth()/(float)mSize.x;
                //Typeface tf = Typeface.create("Helvetica",Typeface.BOLD);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                //paint.setStyle((Style) PDFPaint.Style);
                //paint.setTypeface(tf);
                   //canvas.drawText(scale,0,0,paint);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint.setTextSize(100);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try to change in below method which you can find in ReaderView class

```
private void measureView(View v) {
    // See what size the view wants to be
    v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

    if (!mReflow) {
        // Work out a scale that will fit it to this view
        float scale = Math.min((float) getWidth() / (float) v.getMeasuredWidth(),(float) getHeight() / (float) v.getMeasuredHeight());
        // Use the fitting values scaled by our current scale factor
        v.measure(MeasureSpec.AT_MOST | (int) (v.getMeasuredWidth() * scale  * mScale), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST | (int) (v.getMeasuredHeight() * (scale+0.6f) * mScale));
    } else {
        v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | (int) (v.getMeasuredWidth()),
                View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | (int) (v.getMeasuredHeight()));

    }
}
```